# MySQL: count grouped items?

Tags: mysql

Basically, ok say my DB table has 2 columns: **keyword** and **date**.

I want to select rows but if multiple rows have the same keyword and date I want to group them and get a count of how many there are.

for example instead of getting this:

```
keyword: diamond, date: 20090601
keyword: diamond, date: 20090601
keyword: diamond, date: 20090602
keyword: diamond, date: 20090602
keyword: diamond, date: 20090602
```

I would get this:

```
keyword: diamond, date: 20090601, count: 2
keyword: diamond, date: 20090602, count: 3
```

Not sure how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called the [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause:

```
SELECT keyword, date, COUNT(1) AS count
FROM table
GROUP BY keyword, date
```