# count points for duplicate names for each name in php code

Tags: php, sql, count, duplicates

i have table i got it from display sql records and this table i make by php code , table like this

```
pos.     name       points

 1       john          8
 2       mike          5
 3       mike          9
 4       john          2
```

php code for this table to display records from database from phpmyadmin sql

```html
<?php 

// make connecion
mysql_connect('localhost', 'db user', 'db password');

// Select Database
mysql_select_db ('db name');

$sql="SELECT * FROM wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist";

$records=mysql_query($sql);



?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>الاحصائيات النهائية لمسابقة اكتوبر</title>
</head>

<body>

<table class="wpProQuiz_toplistTable">
    
   <tr>
    <th style="width: 40px;">Pos.</th>
    <th style="">Name</th>
    <th style="width: 60px;">Points</th>
   <tr>
<?php 

 while($wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {
  
  echo "<tr>"; 
  
  echo "<td>".$wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist[toplist_id]."</td>"; 
  
  echo "<td>".$wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist[name]."</td>";
  
  echo "<td>".$wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist[points]."</td>";
  
  echo "</tr>"; 
  
  
  }// End While

?>               
           
                  
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

as u see in the table , i have duplicate names like 'mike' show 2 times .

i want to sum points for each name and array or order names in the table according to the most on the receipt of a number of points for each name like this for past table example

```
pos.     name       points

 1       mike         14
 2       john         10
```

please edit my above php code and type your answer cause i am newbie and can not use code perfect , i need your help quickly , sorry for little english

Comment: Take a look at GROUP BY (sql)

Comment: Do you want it to be in PHP? You could easily sum them up via SQL: `SELECT name, sum(points) as total FROM user.ticket GROUP BY name`

Comment: try using `groupBy` add `groupBy name` in query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: count grouped items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951966/mysql-count-grouped-items)

Comment: when i enter table from SQL in phpmyadmin i see this code 'SELECT * FROM `wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist` WHERE 1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
$sql="SELECT sum(points) as sumpoints , name FROM wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist group by name";

$records=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: thanks for your help but this code just show names as once mike and once john and no duplicate names , but nothing change , what can i do exactly , please explain step by step cause i am newbie

Comment: if you need to get sum of points means you need to group sames(like duplicate ) .so only i am using group by () function

Comment: yes i understand , but it dose not show sum of points for each user , i will give you link to see [link](https://nourena.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%A9/)

Comment: also i can not see order by sum of points , so sorry for disturbing you

Comment: post print_r($resords);

Comment: what array values you have using this query .post your array or php code currently run

Comment: look above for my php code , now i solved sum of points by replace echo "<td>".$wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist[points]."</td>";  **to** echo "<td>".$wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist[sumpoints]."</td>";

Comment: but until now i can not order by names in the table according to the most on the receipt of a number of points for each name like last table for first table , really thank you and waiting you

Comment: hey , now almost i solve everything but i missing something , how to put in 'pos.' in the table 1-2-3-4-5 numbers by DESC

Comment: already i ordered by desc i mean the first column (pos.) in the table and under this cell i want to show number by DESC from 1-2-3-4 to unlimted

Answer (score 0):

You should change your query to do it:

```
mysql> select pos, name, SUM(points) as total from wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist group by name;
+------+------+--------+
| pos  | name | total  |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 | john |     10 |
|    2 | mike |     14 |
+------+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to get the results ordered by the **total** points then you should issue this query (take into account that the **pos** value would be wrong):

```
mysql> select pos, name, SUM(points) as total from wp_wp_pro_quiz_toplist group by name order by total DESC;
+------+------+-------+
| pos  | name | total |
+------+------+-------+
|    2 | mike |    14 |
|    1 | john |    10 |
+------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks for your help  what can i do exactly by this code , please explain step by step cause i am newbie , i mean where , sorry

Comment: hey please tell me about i told you , i need to understand what can i do for query